# Service Worker to Cache WEBAPI data if API have Parameters and Headers (await cache.addAll(API_URLS))

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, service-worker, worker

I have serviceWorker.js in this I am Cache the URL and REsponse data into cache storage

APi Contains the Headers but while using this below method it's getting error to fetch the data How to Pass the headers in this addall array urls .

await cache.addAll(API_URLS);

I am Using Javascript, i required Answers in javascript only.

Adv Thank You

Comment: May I know why you need to store header along with  response?

Comment: I am Using the Azure API ,Required to Subscription KEY to send while requesting

Comment: It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38359925/4262276) might be of help. Basically, instead of just passing an array of url-strings to `addAll()` you pass an array of `Request` objects.

Comment: Yes done its working.Thank you for Answer